# auto enter(nextline) the code as window size decreases in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, brackets

I was using brackets editor and in brackets when the line is with the window code will use the next line 
[image]
but in VS Code the code just goes on 
[image]
 in the same line which is frustrating I googled a lot of the settings but I just don't know what to search for.

i know there is some settings to be changed.

please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt+Z</kbd> or in main menu `View -> Toggle Word Wrap`

Also you can enable it in settings.json

```
// Controls how lines should wrap.
//  - off: Lines will never wrap.
//  - on: Lines will wrap at the viewport width.
//  - wordWrapColumn: Lines will wrap at `editor.wordWrapColumn`.
//  - bounded: Lines will wrap at the minimum of viewport and `editor.wordWrapColumn`.
"editor.wordWrap": "on"
```

Or `File -> Preferences -> Settings`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Mac users: Press <kbd>option + z</kbd>